# Why my directory listing not showing Images folder when deploying a Nodejs app on Vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vercel

I have a Nodejs server that I deployed on Vercel and there is public/uploads folder which contains user's uploaded images but currently I get 404 error when accessing those images.

The file vercel.json contains

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "server.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/uploads/(.*)",
            "dest": "./public/uploads/(.*)"
        },
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "./server.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

can't access images what so ever

I am expecting to access my images from public/uploads.